# How to find the max of two functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Suppose I have a parametric function like `f(v)=max{v-x,-y}` where `0<=v<v_max`, and  `x>=0, y>=0`. I want to find simplify `f(v)` as follows.

`f(v)=max{v-x,y}= -y  if v<x-y, v-x if v>=x-y`
I use the following code, but the problem is that if `x-y<0`, then the condition  `-y  if v<x-y` will not be true.

```
f[v_, x_] := v - x;
g[y_] := -y;
h[v_, x_, y_] :=  f[v, x]*Boole[f[v, x] >= g[y]] + g[y] (1 - Boole[f[v, x] >= g[y]]) // Simplify;
```

Is it possible to explicitly have the conditions that are not listed in True?

Comment: `Not@h[v, x, y][[1, 1, -1]]` is the condition that is represented by the `True`

Comment: Thank you so much. What is the general rule to use it? For example, if I find the integration of h[v, x, y] with respect to v and store it in another variable. 
integration = Integrate[h[v, x, y], {v, 0, vmax}].

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[v_, x_] := v - x;
g[y_] := -y;
h[v_, x_, y_] := 
  f[v, x]*Boole[f[v, x] >= g[y]] + g[y] (1 - Boole[f[v, x] >= g[y]]) // 
   Simplify;

h[v, x, y]
```

[image]

The condition represented by `True` is

```
Not@h[v, x, y][[1, 1, -1]]

(* v + y < x *)
```

For multiple conditions,

```
integration = 
 Assuming[vmax > 0, Integrate[h[v, x, y], {v, 0, vmax}] // Simplify]
```

[image]

The condition represented by `True` is

```
ConditionalExpression[Simplify@Not[Or @@ integration[[1, All, -1]]], 
 vmax > 0]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Would an explicit [`Piecewise`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html) do what you need?

```
h[v_, x_, y_] = 
  Piecewise[{{f[v, x], f[v, x] >= g[y]},
             {g[y],    f[v, x] < g[y]}}]
```

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
v-x & \text{if }v-x\ge -y\\
-y & \text{if }v-x< -y\\
0 & \text{if True}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Please note the [immediate assignment](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/39-immediate-and-delayed-values.html). It makes little sense to have a `Simplify` statement in a [delayed assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html).

Comment: Thank you so much. But, the first condition is valid when 0<=x-y<v<=vmax. Similarly for the second case.